# How to calculate shopping cart product shipping

Tags: javascript

I have products in a cart from different sellers with different shipping prices.

what would be the way to calculate the shipping?

This is what I have so far:
I initialize the variable shipping:

```
public shipping: number;
```

Then I do a **foreach** for the shopping cart

```
  this.cart.forEach(item => {
        this.shipping += item.product.shippingCost;
    });
```

The above is giving me shipping to be 'NAN'.

What would be the way to do this, considering if products are from different sellers.

I am not sure of the real way to go about this.

For example, If different kind of goods (product 1: a book, product 2: a car), are in the cart with different shipping requirements but from the same seller. Do I  have to calculate the shipping for such product differently? Considering this same seller can just bundle the car and the book to one package.

What should be the way to calculate shipping for such a client listing site sale shopping cart?

[image]

Comment: Can you please show what's stored in `cart` array. just copy and paste it here

Comment: Can you show us the values of `item.product.shippingCost`

Comment: Okay.I will upload a more detail image!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize "this.shipping" with 0 before adding values in it.

Edit1:
before this loop, use this statement.

```
this.shipping = 0
```

Comment: I did that, but the resulting shipping for a single item in the cart would be something like this 021, with a leading zero.

Comment: for that you will need to parse that shipping cost to number

Comment: this.shipping += Number(item.product.shippingCost) OR this.shipping += +item.product.shippingCost

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `reduce` to avoid initialize value

```
 this.cart
.map(item => Number(item.product.shippingCost))
.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
```

if you have seller id in this object then you can filter by seller id

```
 this.cart
.filter(item => item.seller_id === SELLER_ID)
.map(item => Number(item.product.shippingCost))
.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next);
```

Note : **SELLER_ID** is your specific seller id